# How to stop Angular Material input labels from floating when the control is readonly

Tags: angular, angular-material

Since Angular 12, material inputs which are **readonly** now have their label float when you click on the input even though you cant actually edit the control.

Here is an example of this behaviour:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/8yg6sm-mlrory

The control is readonly but when you click on it, the label floats.

[image: The label floats when clicked on even though its read only]

Here is an example of how it used to work in Angular 11:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shijse

The control is readonly and when you click on it the label does not float.

[image: The label does not float when clicked on]

Is there a way to regain this behaviour? I don't like the idea that the label floats when the user isn't able to input anything into the control.

Comment: you might try to use the email form control disabled - email = new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

Comment: @sonusindhu yes setting the control to disabled does prevent the label from floating when you click on it.... however, it also adds other styles to the control such as setting the color to grey and the underline to a dotted line.